# Why does this greatest subsequential sum code work?

Tags: r, sum, subsequence

Rosetta Code has the following task, described [here](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Greatest_subsequential_sum):

> "*Given a sequence of integers, find a continuous subsequence which maximizes the sum of its elements, that is, the elements of no other single subsequence add up to a value larger than this one. An empty subsequence is considered to have the sum of   **0**;   thus if all elements are negative, the result must be the empty sequence.*"

This isn't a very complicated problem, and can be comfortably solved in ten lines or less. However, [their R solution](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Greatest_subsequential_sum#R) confused me. I've reproduced it below:

```
max.subseq <- function(x) {
  cumulative <- cumsum(x)
  min.cumulative.so.far <- Reduce(min, cumulative, accumulate=TRUE)
  end <- which.max(cumulative-min.cumulative.so.far)
  begin <- which.min(c(0, cumulative[1:end]))
  if (end >= begin) x[begin:end] else x[c()]
}
```

In particular, I can't see why the `min.cumulative.so.far` variable is needed and the final line's idea of checking if the index of some maximum is greater than the index of a minimum is very strange to me indeed.

So why does this code work? I understand every individual function and its output, but I have no idea why putting them together like this would work, or why it would be picked over a simpler "generate a list of valid subsequences, and pick the one with the greatest sum" approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break it down starting at the result of `cumulative`.

1. `min.cumulative.so.far` will provide you with the minimum `cumulative` before the current index for all indexes.
2. In the next step we calculate the `cumulative` of the best sub-sequence for every element of the sequence, from the `min.cumulative.so.far` to the value at each index. `end` will be the end of the best subsequence which can be 1.
3. This is where it gets interesting: if all values are negative, `end` will be 1 and all values for `cumulative[1:end]` will be negative, so the result of `which.min()` will be 2 as the value is less than 0 (the value at index 1). This will now result in `begin` being larger than `end` and the function will return an empty vector. Otherwise `begin` will be set to the first index after the lowest value before the index `end` which, as we have already established is the last element of the largest sub-sequence based on `cumulative` at index `begin`. This is why `0` is added to the vector. If the relevant `min.so.far` is negative, start with the next value in the vector. If all the `cumulative` values are positive, simply start at the beginning (the added `0` will be the lowest value). The only thing that happens in this step is actually finding the index with the minimum `cumulative` up to index `end`.
4. The return is then trivial. Empty if all values are negative as described above, otherwise `x` from the beginning to the end of the sub-sequence with the largest sum.

**Edge case: all values negative**

```
> x <-  -(1:10)
> cumulative <- cumsum(x)
> cumulative
 [1]  -1  -3  -6 -10 -15 -21 -28 -36 -45 -55
> min.cumulative.so.far <- Reduce(min, cumulative, accumulate=TRUE)
> min.cumulative.so.far
 [1]  -1  -3  -6 -10 -15 -21 -28 -36 -45 -55
> end <- which.max(cumulative-min.cumulative.so.far)
> end
[1] 1
> begin <- which.min(c(0, cumulative[1:end]))
# c(0, cumulative[1:end]) is c(0, -1) in this case as 1:end = 1:1
> begin
[1] 2
> if (end >= begin) x[begin:end] else x[c()]
integer(0)
```

**Standard Case**

```
> x <- c(1, 5, -9, 3, 7, 1, 2, 4, 5, -6)
> cumulative <- cumsum(x)
> cumulative
 [1]  1  6 -3  0  7  8 10 14 19 13
> min.cumulative.so.far <- Reduce(min, cumulative, accumulate=TRUE)
> min.cumulative.so.far
 [1]  1  1 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3
> end <- which.max(cumulative-min.cumulative.so.far)
> end
[1] 9
> begin <- which.min(c(0, cumulative[1:end]))
> begin
[1] 4
> if (end >= begin) x[begin:end] else x[c()]
[1] 3 7 1 2 4 5
```

Comment: Is your step two the line ```end <- which.max(cumulative-min.cumulative.so.far)```?

Comment: Amended the post s.t. step 2 includes the calculation of `end`. The non-trivial part is the variable `begin` in step 3. Thanks for the comment.